Numbering of entries (1, 2, 3 ...)
is there any way to add ascending numbers to entries archive, i.e. Entry #1 of 100, Entry #2 of 100, #3 of 100 etc. Thanks in advance.

Since you're using pagination, you can calculate the offset using the current page and number of items per page.
{% set limit = 10 %}
{% set archiveQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('blog')
    .limit(limit)
%}

{% paginate archiveQuery as pageInfo, posts %}

{% set offset = (pageInfo.currentPage - 1) * limit %}

{% for post in posts %}
    Entry {{ offset + loop.index }} of {{ pageInfo.total }}
{% endfor %}


Brilliant ! Thx a lot !

I’m not sure if this is what you’re asking for, but you can number fetched entries inside a for loop in Twig using the current iteration of the loop (loop.index).
{% set entries = craft.entries.all() %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    Entry #{{ loop.index }} of {{ entries|length }}
{% endfor %}

To make this work when paginating entries, you can add the current page’s first entry number (pageInfo.first) to the zero-indexed iteration of the loop (loop.index0).
{% set entryQuery = craft.entries.limit(10) %}
{% paginate entryQuery as pageInfo, entries %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    Entry #{{ pageInfo.first + loop.index0 }} of {{ pageInfo.total }}
{% endfor %}

References:
https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/development/element-queries.html#navigating-pages
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

ok, thx, will try and let you know

It works, but, for pagination state, for every next page, it starts from 1 of total, rather than continuing from the previous page.

You didn’t mention that in your question, but I’ve added a second code sample to my answer for the case when you’re paginating entries.
